# How can I send an email with my vb.net code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp, smtpclient

I am using asp.net / vb.net. I want to send an email. My code does not send an email as it is. I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.

I created a file called email.text that holds the email template. The rest of the code to send the email is below. I removed personal information from my code.

I setup the SMTP connection as such:

```
Private SMTPClientConnection As SmtpClient
Sub New()
    SMTPClientConnection = New SmtpClient
    SMTPClientConnection.Host = "HOSTHERE"
    SMTPClientConnection.Port = PORTHERE
    SMTPClientConnection.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
End Sub
```

Then I created a function to send the email:

```
Private Shared Function SendEmail(ByVal emailUser As String, ByVal bodyMessage As List(Of String), ByVal priority As MailPriority) As Boolean
    Dim functionReturnValue As Boolean = False

    Try

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailUser) Then

            If Regex.IsMatch(emailUser, "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.+_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.|[-]{1,2})[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$") Then

                Using SMTPClientConnection
                    Dim smtpMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
                    Dim _with1 = smtpMessage
                    _with1.[To].Add(New MailAddress(emailUser))
                    _with1.From = New MailAddress("Test Email" & " <email@email.com>")
                    _with1.ReplyToList.Add(New MailAddress("email@email.com"))
                    _with1.Subject = "Test Email"
                    _with1.Priority = priority
                    Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyMessage(0), Nothing, "text/html")
                    Dim plainView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyMessage(1), Nothing, "text/plain")
                    _with1.AlternateViews.Add(plainView)
                    _with1.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
                    SMTPClientConnection.Send(smtpMessage)
                    Return True
                End Using
            Else
                Throw New SmtpException("Invalid email.")
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Return functionReturnValue
End Function
```

I use the function on my code here:

```
            Dim plainBody As String = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("email.txt"))
            plainBody = plainBody.Replace("%Name%", emailName)

            Dim emailBody As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(New String() {plainBody})
            SendEmail("email@email.com", emailBody, MailPriority.Normal)
```

Comment: Well. start removing that empty try catch block. If there is an error you will never see it and you cannot tell us what error happens here.

Comment: Did you first test your connection-the host and port name are correct?

Comment: @Steve @salsinga Yes, the host and port are correct. I believe my issue is at `Using SMTPClientConnection` which is showing `Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error message is clear. The variable *SmtpClientConnection* is an instance variable (it exists as a different entity in any class instance where is declared) but you are trying to use inside a *Shared* method (a method that exists without a class instance). Inside this kind of methods you cannot use instance variables because you don't have an instance from which the method could pick the variable value and use it.

The solution could be to remove the *Shared* keyword from the method and then, whenever you want to call the method you need to create an instance of the class where the instance variable *SmtpClientConnection* is initialized and ready to be used in the following call to the *SendMail* method.

However, you could still use the *Shared* method but should remove the instance variable and create it inside the *SmtpClient* method:

```
Private Shared Function SendEmail(ByVal emailUser As String, ByVal bodyMessage As List(Of String), ByVal priority As MailPriority) As Boolean
    Dim functionReturnValue As Boolean = False

    Try

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailUser) Then

            If Regex.IsMatch(emailUser, "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.+_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+((\.|[-]{1,2})[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$") Then


               Dim SMTPClientConnection As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient
               SMTPClientConnection.Host = "HOSTHERE"
               SMTPClientConnection.Port = PORTHERE
               SMTPClientConnection.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network                
               Using SMTPClientConnection
                    Dim smtpMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
                    ......
                    SMTPClientConnection.Send(smtpMessage)
                    Return True
                End Using
            Else
                Throw New SmtpException("Invalid email.")
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
       ' No point in catching an exception and doing nothing here.
       ' You can log the exception somewhere and then throw it again
       LogException(ex)
       Throw
       ' or just remove the try/catch block.
    End Try
    Return functionReturnValue
End Function
```

In this way the variable is created only when needed and destroyed as well when the using statement ends. Take also note of the comments relative to the Try/Catch block.